# How can I reload only a part of code - Java

Tags: java, javascript, reload

I have a JSP page that at the end comes a pop-up window from a javascript, I want after the users click to reload only a specific part of the JSP page more specific one if - loop want to be reloaded one more time ...can this happened or the idea is totally wrong ?

Comment: Look up [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) requests.

Comment: Read about PPR (partial page rendering) and AJAX (asynchronous JavaScript and XML)!

Comment: Reload in a sense- Need to send a call to java ? If so  can be refreshed using ajax

Comment: you can use component refresh with ajax

Comment: Are you using raw servlets+jsp, or do you use a framework ? In the former case, I suggest you take a look at jQuery, a nice javascript lib that simplifies AJAX calls ; in the latter case, check if your framework has built-in AJAX capabilities - most do nowadays.

Comment: can you please write an example with AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

> AJAX is the art of exchanging data with a server, and updating parts
>   of a web page - without reloading the whole page.

jQuery has a very nice [ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

To load html pages, you could use [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) like this:

```
$("#result").load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

You can also generate dynamic html by calling a REST function of a php page using a different url. Example:

```
var data = { limit: 25, otherProp: "val" }
$("#result").load( "getHtmldata.php", data);
```

Comment: This is the code from the Javascript and I want to keep the allowDelete after the reloading or to reload again only the if-loop that waits the allowdelete .
`<%
if (Error) {
%>
<script type"text/javascript">
<!--
var keepAlert = confirm('<%=msg%>');
if(keepAlert){
 <%allowDelete = false;%>
}
else{
 
 document.location.reload(true);
 <%allowDelete = true;%>
 allowDelete = true;
 function LoadOnce()
 {
  windows.location.reload(true);
  alert("refreshhhh the page");
 }
 
} 
//-->
</script>
<%
}
%>
</form>
</body onLoad="LoadOnce()">
</html>'`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. can you explain.